# Using CMake with IBM Rhapsody (code generator)

Tags: windows, cmake, rhapsody

I am in the process of using CMake to automate a build process on Windows.  The first step of the build process involves using IBM Rhapsody to generate the code to be built.

I have found that Rhapsody can be run headless (i.e. from command line) with RhapsodyCL.exe.  Before proceeding with CMake I had the following questions:

1. Is this use-case (auto-generated code) supported by CMake?
2. How do I call RhapsodyCL.exe as a *required* CMake pre-build step?  What is the recommended way to do the code generation as a pre-build step?
3. Since all my code is being generated by Rhapsody, how should my CMakeLists.txt look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question at the following site:

[Integrating a code generator with CMake](https://blog.kangz.net/posts/2016/05/26/integrating-a-code-generator-with-cmake/)

Comment: do you have an example rhapsody model that demonstrates using cmake?